# Can't connect to a database with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to connect to my localhost database but my code doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;', 'root', 'pass');
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    die("Can't connect with Database");
}

?>
```

Can someone please hlep me?
thanks

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: First change your quotes!

Comment: if an answer works for you choose one to accept!

Comment: And surely this question never be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put the database name in it. And you need to display the error.

```
 <?php
        try 
        {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'pass');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Y do you fancy copy/pasting answers

Comment: No?? didn't saw your comment! This is just some basic PDO so the answer could easily be the same? And what would be the point of copying your answer?

Comment: It's just amazing, how reputation points attract people. You'd better care of your knowledge rather of reputation points.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer??? It work's and I didn't copy anything! So I don't see the problem! I'm just trying to help him!

Answer (score 2):

Please specify the db name

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Why on the earth this answer got 3 upvotes? Why vote if you have no idea on the right answer?

Comment: @YourCommonSense This is because, that partially answers the question stated in the body : *I want to connect to my localhost database*